# Can't create android release application but debug application create with no errors

Tags: android, debugging, gradle, release

Why I could build application in debug mode with no errors, but when I want to create release I'm getting a lot of similar exceptions:

.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5667337e4903249f37626ea9eff27615/transformed/jetified-activity-ktx-1.7.0/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/activity-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0